# Variable not defined in Laravel 5.5 each loop

Tags: php

I'm having a problem with Laravel 5.5.

I have a public function in my controller, and inside that function I have this:

```
$test = 'testing';

$products = Products::all();
$products->each(function ($item, $key) {
    $price = $item->price;
    dd($test);
});
```

And I get the following:

```
ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Undefined variable: test
```

How is that even possible? Is there something I am missing? 
BTW, if I do:

```
dd($price);
```

It dies and prints the price so the loop is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use use($variable) method in order for it to have an access to the variable inside the anonymous function.

```
    $test = 'testing';

    $products = Products::all();
    $products->each(function ($item, $key) use ($test) {
        $price = $item->price;
        dd($test);
    });
```

Comment: Glad to be of help

Comment: sorry I got a followup question: How can I modify the variable $test inside the loop?

Comment: Note that in order for you to be able to modify $test and retrieve the modified value outside of the scope of the anonymous function, it must be referenced in the closure using &.                     $products->each(function ($item, $key) use (&$test)

Answer (score 1):

Have a read about [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

```
$products->each(function ($item, $key) use ($test) {
    $price = $item->price;
    dd($test);
});
```

Comment: Damn I've been learning PHP and never came up with this problem. Thanks!